# How comparison between two list using streams?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have first list contains list of objects Users,

```
List<UserDetails> resultUesrList=array.stream().map(result>parseObject(result)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

each object from list user contains list ranges:

```
//Retrieve user ranges details 
    List<Range> ranges=user.getRanges();
```

on another side I have other list

```
account.getRanges()
```

I want to forloop list of users then get ranges each user then compare each range in user on all ranges in account.getRanges() using streams.

I don't know how can do this in streams but as initially I do the below it's correct and how can compare each other :

```
resultUesrList.stream().flatMap(user->user.getRanges().stream().map(i->i)).collect(Collectors.toList());
account.getRanges().stream().map(j->j).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

i write the code in traditional way to be more clear:

```
    private void fillUsersAccount(Account account,String companyID) throws Exception {

    //call IAM to get company details
    ApplicationResponse response = RESTServiceUtils.callService(ApplicationContextProvider.getApplicationContext().getBean(EnvironmentConfig.class).getAccountURL()+companyID, false, false, null, ApplicationResponse.class);  
    Object companyObjectDetails = response.getResult();
    ArrayList<?> array =(ArrayList<?>)companyObjectDetails;  
    List<UserDetails> resultUesrList=array.stream().map(result->parseObject(result)).collect(Collectors.toList());

    //get list of users 
    for(int i=0;i<resultUesrList.size();i++) {              
        //get user details
        UserDetails user=resultUesrList.get(i);             
        //Retrieve user ranges details 
        List<Range> ranges=user.getRanges();    
        //get ranges in user
        for(int j=0;j<ranges.size();j++) {                  
            //get range user 
            Range rangeUser=ranges.get(j);                  
            //get ranges inner account 
            for (Range rangeOuter : account.getRanges()) {                      
                //check if range id equals and type range
                if(rangeUser.getRangeId().equals(rangeOuter.getRangeId()) && rangeUser.getRangeType().equals(rangeOuter.getRangeType()))    {                       
                    if(rangeOuter.getUsers()!=null) {
                        rangeOuter.getUsers().add(user);
                    }else {
                        List<UserDetails> users=new ArrayList<UserDetails>();
                        users.add(user);
                        rangeOuter.setUsers(users);
                    }                                               
                }                   
            }               
        }                       
    }                   
}
```

Comment: So you have a working solution? What's the problem?

Comment: @shmosel i can't compare between two list ?

Comment: @shmosel using streams

Comment: Why do you think you have to use streams?

Comment: what do you want as the end result? I can't seem to tell.

Comment: @JoeC i want increase performance code , and write minimum code

Comment: @Aominè at the end if ranges equals i will add user in ranges object

Comment: Streams will not give you the performance impact you seem to be expecting, and they're not really designed for things like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three nestings: account `Range`s, `UserDetails`s and user `Range`s, so it can't readily be done in a single swoop. It's easier to factor out the self-contained pieces into methods that handle the details.

Also, you want to construct new `Range`s to add back on to your account, instead of modifying the existing `Range`s.

```
List<Range> newAccountRanges = account.getRanges().stream()
  .map( accountRange -> new Range( 
    accountRange.getRangeId(),
    accountRange.getRangeType(),
    findMatchingUsers( accountRange ) ) )
  .collect( Collectors.toList() );
...
List<UserDetails> findMatchingUsers( Range forAccount ) {
  resultUesrList.stream()
    .filter( user -> user.getRanges().stream()
       .anyMatch( userRange -> checkRange( forAccount, userRange ) )
    .collect( Collectors.toList() );
...
boolean checkRange( Range forAccount, Range forUser ) {
  return forAccount.getRangeId().equals( forUser.getRangeId() ) &&
    forAccount.getRangeType().equals( forUser.getRangeType() );
}
```

Comment: i add the below method `List<UserDetails> findMatchingUsers( Range forAccount,List<UserDetails> resultUesrList) {
  resultUesrList.stream().filter( user -> user.getRanges().stream().findAny( userRange -> checkRange( forAccount, userRange ))).collect(Collectors.toList());
 }` give me compilation error **The method findAny() in the type Stream<Range> is not applicable for the arguments ((<no type> userRange) -> {})**

Comment: Sorry, that should be `anyMatch()`.